# Creating a separate class for schemas in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm seeing if there is any value in creating separate classes for schemas in pyspark (like model in traditional MVC architecture).

There are a lot of intermediate results in the pipeline and I'm a bit paranoid about how none of them are type-checked. So output of step1, 2, 3.. and so on are being stored in the disk but at the time of the `spark.write`, none of them are actually being checked (I'm assuming spark actually will throw an error if it can't write to the disk).

Is it completely necessary to do type checking for pyspark, and if so, what would be the best way of handling it?

Comment: schema at any intermediate step can be checked like df.printSchema(). However, if you want to rigorously test it, go through https://blog.cambridgespark.com/unit-testing-with-pyspark-fb31671b1ad8 . If final intention is to write, I dont think your schema matters, except that it writes in the expected format. Is your question answered?

Comment: I'm afraid if I do printSchema, it would show in somewhere in log buried.. I think what I want to do is something like this http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/ and then use an instance of a class like this to check if each row is having the same schema.